# Return function from inside custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the below custom hook;

```
export default function useFetch(url) {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchresponse = async () => {
            // code to fetch response from api
        }
        fetchresponse();
    }, [url]);

    return [response];
}
```

While the above works fine from the start of my functional component, I want to make this reusable and invoke them from other places in my main component (e.g. button click) i.e. hit api on button click.
Thus, I want to return an executable function, which can be invoked on say button click.

How can I do that and considering I have a useEffect here inside my custom hook ?

Answer (score 3):

Just define the function outside the `useEffect` hook.

Then it will be in scope to return.

```
function useFetch(url) {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState();

    const fetchresponse = async () => {
        // code to fetch response from api
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchresponse();
    }, [url]);

    return [response, fetchresponse];
}
```

Optionally wrap the function in `useCallback` so it doesn't get redefined with each render.

Comment: Thanks...in terms of the return value (e.g. api response here), since I'll need that data response when I invoke the executable function (e.g. fetchresponse here) on say button click, should I also return the same thing from this function (fetchresponse here) that I am returning from the overall hook ?

Comment: Generally your design should be that calling `fetchresponse` updates teh `response` state which is already being used in the component that is using this hook so it will trigger a rerender of that component.

Comment: Hmm ok...got that point...though trying that way, I feel like I am now running into another issue...i.e. in my main component, I can have say 3 separate API calls and each of them correspond to a different state (e.g. 3 diff grids data)...so not sure how that can be achieved...